# DELETE if return more than 1 MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I need delete rows if I have more than 1. Why it doesn't work?

```
if
    (SELECT count(*)
FROM Table1 where Name = 'TEST')

RETURN (2)

BEGIN
    DELETE MIN(Id) FROM Table1 where Name = 'TEST'
END
```

Comment: You got serious syntax errors in your query. One question: the column `Id` is a unique key?

Comment: If you found n rows (n > 1) then you want to delete n - 1 rows or delete first row? I guest you are trying to delete row which have min id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the column `id` if the primary key. So there will be at most 1 record for each id. Furthermore, there won't be more than 2 records with the same name.

First of all, you need to determine the duplicated records (2 records with the same name).
That can be done like this:

```
SELECT   Name,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     Table1
GROUP BY Name
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Then, get for each pair the one with the lowest id (the inner query is the one I showed above):

```
SELECT   Name,
         MIN(id) AS min_id
FROM     Table1
WHERE    Name IN (SELECT Name
                  FROM   (SELECT   Name,
                                   COUNT(*)
                          FROM     Table1
                          GROUP BY Name
                          HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
                         )
                 )
GROUP BY Name
```

Finally, delete the desired records:

```
DELETE
FROM   Table1
WHERE  id IN (SELECT min_id
              FROM   (SELECT   Name,
                               MIN(id) AS min_id
                      FROM     Table1
                      WHERE    Name IN (SELECT Name
                                        FROM   (SELECT   Name,
                                                         COUNT(*)
                                                FROM     Table1
                                                GROUP BY Name
                                                HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
                                               )
                                       )
                      GROUP BY Name
                     )
             )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is all wrong.  You don't delete from an expression; you delete from a table.

You can use window functions and updatable CTEs to do what you want.  If you want to delete *all* copies of a row, use `count(*)`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by t1.name) as cnt
      from table1 t1
      where Name = 'TEST'
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt > 1;
```

I am guessing that you actually want to *keep* the row with the minimum id.  In that case, use `row_number()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.name order by t1.id) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
      where Name = 'TEST'
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is like below.
It deletes all records for which another one with the same name and a higher ID exists:

```
DELETE
FROM   Table1 tab1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   Table1 tab2
               WHERE  tab1.Name = tab2.Name
                 AND  tab2.id > tab1.id);
```

It works on Oracle. Not sure for SQL-Server.